# Acumatica 2018 R2 Mobile - Locks up when attempting to add a new screen

Tags: acumatica

After Summit 2019, we were excited to start working on updates for 2018R2, and I practiced adding mobile screens for our custom modules in my sandbox.

We decided to fully refresh our DEV instance and reapply our customizations. No problem there, but when I try "Add New Screen" in the mobile section and then try to enter my screen number, the mouse goes to "waiting" and I can't add my new screen.  Eventually, I get a "timed out" message.  Same problem even when trying to add a standard Acumatica screen.  Everything else in the project and Acumatica web interface seems to work fine.

Any ideas on where to look for what is preventing adding a new screen?

I'm on Build 18.209.0021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified by Acumatica support as a bug.  Upgrade to a new release for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an Ajax issue in the customization project editor. After callback to server the client page javascript is stuck waiting on the server response. You can try using Chrome browser which has less of those Ajax hangs and update Chrome if you're already using it.

There is also a known issue specifically affecting 2018 R2 Mobile that leads to generic error `Sequence contains no matching element` on mobile detail page. Based on your question this doesn't seem to be the issue you are having but you can give the workaround to this bug a try:

1. Open Generic Inquiry screen (SM208000)
2. Select FS-ServiceOrder inquiry, uncheck Expose to mobile and save
3. On Apply Updates screen (SM203510), click on Restart Application

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.  However, I'm having the same problem on 3 instances of the same build version.  I will try a clean install on my laptop and try before and after applying the customization project.

Comment: I've had success with version 18.202.0028

Comment: We opened a support case, but no answer yet.  I can add the pages in my local sandbox and port the customization project back to my DEV instance.  At that point, it allows me to edit the pages that are in the project already.  I'd like to know how to fix DEV and QA so this isn't broken, but we have a workaround for now.